# Wraping 3DES key with itself

Tags: encryption, 3des

I have a question that looks weird even to myself.

I am translating a program written about 15 years ago to C#. A part of this program is key generation and storing it in a file medium.

Here is the part that I am concerned. This specific method generates a 3DES derived key from a master 3DES key that we call it `Key1`.

This method uses `Key1` to wrap `Key1` which we call it `wrap1`.
in next step it uses the `Key1` to wrap `wrap1` which we call it `wrap2`.
`wrap2` is stored in medium and `Key1` and `wrap1` is lost.

From my understanding, a wrapped key should be unwrapped before being used for encryption and decryption; However I'm not sure if we can unwrap a key without having the key that used to wrap it.

Please note I do not have access to the part of program that uses this key to see how it is used.

**Question**  is it possible to retrieve the key that is wrapped this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why?  Wrapping a key with itself is pointless.  It's like buying dehydrated water: just add water to reconstitute.  You need the key `key1` to decrypt `wrap1` -- and then what do you get back?  You get back `key1`, which is what you already had.

Of course, someone who doesn't have the key (and can't guess it) cannot decrypt the wrapped key.  That's how key wrapping works.  So, no, given just `wrap1` or just `wrap2`, you cannot deduce the value of `key1`.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought, I needed a confirmation that I am not wrong. The software is too old and may be the developer didn't have a proper understanding of encryption key. What I am thinking is he generated a totally random key and they used wrapped key as key itself. I cannot confirm this until I receive other part of application. Interesting that this software worked for 15 years and nobody complained about security breach!